# Angular: Instantiate object error, can't set property

Tags: angular, typescript

So I'm trying to populate my array but I fail to instantiate it in the first place.

Model:

```
user: User = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  adress: ""
}
order: Order = {
  OrderId: "",
  User: this.user,
  TotalPrice: 0,
  OrderItems: []
```

}

and here I'm trying to populate my Order:

```
    this.Identity.getMail().then(user => this.order.OrderId == user.email);
this.order.User = this.user;
this.order.TotalPrice = this.cartTotal;
this.cartItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  this.order.OrderItems[index].ProductName = item.productName,
  this.order.OrderItems[index].ProductPrice = item.price,
  this.order.OrderItems[index].ProductQuantity = item.quantity
})
```

I am getting this error:

```
CartFullComponent.html:21 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'ProductName' of undefined
```

So how do I instantiate the order.OrderItems so they'll accept some values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this.order.OrderItems.push(item)` instead of assign properties.

```
this.Identity.getMail().then(user => this.order.OrderId == user.email);
this.order.User = this.user;
this.order.TotalPrice = this.cartTotal;
this.cartItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  this.order.OrderItems.push({ 
    ProductName : item.productName, 
    ProductPrice : item.price,
    ProductQuantity : item.quantity
  });
})
```

Comment: But my item isn't an OrderItem. I just need three values of the item. How'd I get around this? It's a CartItem which owns the same three properties as OrderItem but also several more I do not want as OrderItems